# How do I group by nth business day within month in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame grouped by (year, month).  I'd like to look at statistics of the nth row in each (year, month) group -- what's the best way to do that?

So my setup is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.bdate_range('2012-1-1', periods=250)
data = np.random.rand(250,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
group = df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month])
```

So each group is simply:

```
group.get_group((2012,1))

                   A         B         C         D
2012-01-02  0.981690  0.751655  0.040473  0.586829
2012-01-03  0.079392  0.726818  0.568717  0.916406
2012-01-04  0.138018  0.550194  0.321462  0.300273
2012-01-05  0.252901  0.169159  0.941170  0.733971
2012-01-06  0.054530  0.547185  0.751854  0.014632
2012-01-09  0.477299  0.411725  0.867734  0.986216
2012-01-10  0.791581  0.975181  0.453106  0.722259
2012-01-11  0.519475  0.667305  0.521249  0.114595
2012-01-12  0.240605  0.934308  0.957045  0.077284
2012-01-13  0.581049  0.946498  0.961401  0.733273
2012-01-16  0.534614  0.474576  0.580191  0.373324
2012-01-17  0.137119  0.760280  0.985439  0.044371
2012-01-18  0.966209  0.213359  0.333371  0.746351
2012-01-19  0.676534  0.370279  0.710987  0.061505
2012-01-20  0.058050  0.557478  0.116016  0.964448
2012-01-23  0.190743  0.900814  0.064952  0.369975
2012-01-24  0.048135  0.878783  0.970095  0.363559
2012-01-25  0.343305  0.023731  0.514298  0.131724
2012-01-26  0.626055  0.230893  0.557264  0.871486
2012-01-27  0.212099  0.287510  0.260152  0.634898
2012-01-30  0.233956  0.457482  0.516915  0.738543
2012-01-31  0.011327  0.161360  0.804554  0.897392
```

I'd like to get, say, the mean of the i-th row across all groups (i.e., mean of i-th business day in each month).  So the output will have ~23 rows (or whatever the max. no. of business days seen in a month is) and columns 'A' through 'D'.

As a second step, what's the best way of "flattening" the data so that the output is simply a Series indexed by (i, c) where i is 0 through 22 as above and c is 'A' through 'D'.

I've tried iterating through groups, resetting the index and concatenating the frames, but it feels like I'm overlooking some much simpler way!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be happy to discover the method called `nth`. To access the 9th entry for each month, for example,

```
In [15]: group.nth(9)
Out[15]: 
                A         B         C         D
2012 1   0.259695  0.670270  0.467452  0.796057
     2   0.744701  0.633857  0.530602  0.978068
     3   0.901194  0.684747  0.091563  0.582004
     4   0.728239  0.421065  0.044452  0.750780
     5   0.792513  0.016461  0.646832  0.858187
     6   0.662756  0.753480  0.030328  0.105000
     7   0.630161  0.473097  0.504618  0.156850
     8   0.143587  0.955368  0.939281  0.632951
     9   0.115629  0.310003  0.170585  0.166392
     10  0.458202  0.293087  0.171136  0.106911
     11  0.098920  0.275812  0.057490  0.683633
     12  0.601598  0.663051  0.094602  0.500480
```

To solve your second question -- generating a Series indexed by day and column name like `('A', 1)` -- use `df1.unstack().squeeze()`. The unstacking reshapes it just the way you want, and `squeeze` converts the result from a single-column DataFrame to a Series.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  It is surprising though that despite all the documentation for Pandas, it can be difficult to find functions to meet specific needs.  For instance, I still can't seem to find anything on this nth function.  I have some other questions regarding indices, but will ask separately.

Comment: I discovered this in [the book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do). But your point definitely stands: the documentation should advertise this feature. Funnily enough, this very question is already the second Google result for "pandas groupby nth."

Comment: I actually have a question on this function...lets say there are only 5 rows that have the index for the month of april...would the resulting row for month-index 4 be all Nan or would it just grab the 5th row?

Comment: 5th row, if I understand you correctly. ``grouped.get_group(...)`` is good for grabbing rows with a specific index, as opposed to the nth index.